# RecyclerView empty after SwipeRefreshLayout pull onRefresh event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement a Swipe down Refresh Widget for a RecyclerView but am receiving some strange behavior. Here is what the working recyclerView with cardViews looks like. I've included the XML view definition below:

[image]

**The issue:**

After refreshing, the RecyclerView (**recycler_view**) which resides inside the SwipeRefreshLayout view (**swipe_refresh_main**) does not populate with any cardViews:

[image]

The cardViews only become visible after I scroll down past the third, invisible item. I believe this is because of how the RecyclerAdapter works, loading and unloading views depending on their screen visibility. This makes sense in my case because only when the fourth item becomes partially visible, do the previous cardViews also appear.

[image]

I examined the view hierarchy before and after and it is evident that the layouts containing the cardViews aren't present after refreshing:

**Layout pre-refresh:**(notice the three layouts containing visible cardViews)

[image]

**Layout post-refresh:**(notice the empty recyclerView)

[image]

I know this has something to do with how the refresh listener responds to the swipe refresh action, but I can't figure out why it isn't redisplaying the view prior to refresh.

**Refresh Listener calls this method:**

```
@Override
public void showWordList(ArrayList<Word> wordArrayList){
    if(mWordRecyclerAdapter == null){
        mUnfilteredDataSet = wordArrayList;
        mWordRecyclerAdapter = new WordRecyclerAdapter(wordArrayList, this, this);
        mWordRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(dataSetMode);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mWordRecyclerAdapter);
    }else{
        mWordRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(dataSetMode);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mWordRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

The filter method inside of my recyclerAdapter rebuilds the arrayList dataset based on which menu item is selected. In this case, for the refresh, the arrayList remains unchanged:

**getFilter method:**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mWordArrayList = (ArrayList<Word>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

I started to suspect that the notifyDataSetChanged method might have some something to do with this, but I'm not sure. I'm now leaning towards some sort of band-aid fix, such as a method that will force the view to scroll or to reload. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

**XML Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--Main activity UI-->
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_100">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            >
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/search_box"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:popupBackground="#ffff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:hint="Español o Inglés"
                android:completionThreshold="2"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_query_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify_grey600_24dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_clear_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_grey600_36dp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_main">

            <!--Main CardView holder-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <!--Nav Fragments container-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--Drawer Nav UI-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to call setAdapter in if and else part. You can just update the underlying data that you provide to the adapter and refresh by calling notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It's always nice to have a second set of eyes.